# Convert and combine arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hey I need your help in respect of converting arrays in javascript. Please look on my output data:

```
Answers: { 
 '0': { '0': 'ans 1' },
 '1': { '0': 'ans 11', '1': 'ans 22', '2': 'ans 33' } 
}
correctAnswers: { 
 '1': { '0': true, '1': true } 
}
```

And I would like if indexes doesn't match set `false`, so I expect following array:

```
convertArray = [[false], [true, true, false]]
```

For this task I use following function

```
var choiceBoolean = [];
for(corrAns in Answers){
   let tempArr = [];              
   Object.keys(Answers[corrAns]).forEach(k => 
   tempArr[k] = correctAnswers[corrAns][k] || false)
   choiceBoolean.push(Array.apply(null, tempArr).map(Boolean))
}
```

Unfortunately I receive error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the keys from `answer` with another mapped array from the inner keys by checking correct answers.

This solution works with a check if the correct answer exist and then it checks the inner key.

```
correct[k] && correct[k][l] || false
^^^^^^^^^^                            check first if exists
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^           take a truthy value
                               ^^^^^  if not take false
```

```js
var answers = { 0: { 0: 'ans 1' }, 1: { 0: 'ans 11', 1: 'ans 22', 2: 'ans 33' } },
    correct = { 1: { 0: true, 1: true } },
    result = Object
        .keys(answers)
        .map(k => Object.keys(answers[k]).map(l => correct[k] && correct[k][l] || false));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help...again